# Show that all the zeros of $\int_0^z \exp(-w^2/2)\, \mathrm{d}w$ lie in a particular domain

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, statistics, roots, error-function

> Show that all the zeros of 
>   $$f(z)=\int_0^z \exp(-w^2/2)\, \mathrm{d}w$$
>   lie in the domain $\{z:\mathrm{Re}(z^2)<0\}$ except $0$.

Also with some confusing hints: Consider the function $f$ maps the diagonals $y=x$ and $y=-x$ to the Cornu's spiral. Verify this and consider the boundary curve of the domain $z:\mathrm{Re}(z^2)>0$ and $0<r<|z|<R$ for some small $r$.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the error function in your solution?

Comment: @MichaelLee I think so.

Comment: Can you show the first part, i.e. that the image is the Cornu Spiral, $C$?  If so, that sectorial domain with $r$ and $R$ you're talking about is getting mapped inside one of the two inner, circular domains of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus C$.  Though I don't think you have to do all that computation; you can use the open mapping theorem for analytic functions.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @JohnSamples I can prove the first part. But I don’t know how to deal with the rest. Could you explain more, or write an answer containing some sketch?